# I am using Laragon. After I updated my Windows, I found that I need to turn off the advanced firewall in McAfee in order to access the phpMyAdmin

Tags: laravel, apache, phpmyadmin, laragon, mcafee

I am using Laragon. After I updated my Windows, I found that I need to turn off the advanced firewall in McAfee in order to run my Laravel project and access the phpMyAdmin database.

that's not the first time that this error occur for me when I tried to access the phpmyadmin database:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.0.15 Server at localhost
> Port 80

I tried to reinstall Laragon and its works, but this time when I turn off the McAfee firewall it works, but it's not a good choice to turn off the firewall,
so what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't understand what is the problem, but when I turn on the McAfee firewall back, everything works for me,

**So the solution was: to turn off the McAfee firewall and turn it on back.**

but still unable to understand what was the problem

Comment: advice, there are plenty of DBMS better than PhpMyAdmin